# Error in accessing Tidyverse Package in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, dbplyr

I recently updated my tidyverse package (version 1.3.1) and am getting the following error:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘dbplyr’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

Previous entries on this site have suggested I should uninstall and reinstall the dbplyr package and try again. I attempted to do this and now got the following set of errors:

```
> install.packages("dbplyr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘dplyr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
       binary source needs_compilation
cli     3.2.0  3.3.0              TRUE
dplyr   1.0.8  1.0.9              TRUE
dbplyr  2.1.1  2.2.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1256176 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1381331 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\ClimLab\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\ClimLab\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘cli’
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\ClimLab\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘dplyr’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0CQ3EQ\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘dbplyr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 670569 bytes (654 KB)
downloaded 654 KB

* installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0CQ3EQ\downloaded_packages’
```

From here it is suggested I install the Rtools package, which I attempted to do so to find out that Rtools is not available for the version of R I have (which is the most recent one). I'm also a bit confused on why R is thinking I'm trying to build a package, I just want to have tidyverse back!

Does anyone have any advice? I'm certainly not a computer scientist and a lot of these errors don't really make a ton of sense to me. My tidyverse was running fine, but I was encouraged because it was struggling with some functions, to update it and now have all of these issues to the point where nothing runs at all.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You say you have the most recent R version - which I assume is 4.2.1 - but you are trying to load tidyverse built for an older version (4.0.5). The messages regarding dbplyr and Rtools are not really relevant. Try restarting R, then reinstalling tidyverse from binary, not source (which should be the default). You probably need to reinstall all packages, if you have gone from 4.0.5 to 4.2.1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Doing the binary install seemed to solve the problem. I appreciate your time!